# Possible to create a SQL stored procedure for use for all databases

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, global

I have a stored procedure, in one database within my SQL server, that sets permissions to all stored procedures at once for that particulat database. Is there a way to create this stored procedure in a way were I can call it easily from any database within the SQL server and if so how do I go about doing such a thing

Comment: Not to my knowledge - at least not in any of the database systems I know. Stored procedures are always part of a single database - there's no "global" scope for those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have a stored procedure, in one database within my SQL server, that
>   sets permissions to all stored procedures at once for that particular
>   database.*

You could archive the same result much easier:

- create a new role, e.g. `db_executor`

  ```
  CREATE ROLE db_executor
  ```
- grant that role execute permissions without specifying any objects:

  ```
  GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
  ```

This role now has execute permissions on **all** stored procedures and functions - and it will even get the same permissions for **any future stored procedure** that you add to your database!

Just assign this role to the users you need and you're done....

Comment: Marc, this makes sense. I was wondering though where do I create the role, which level within the server (specific database or somewhere else) and when I go to assign the user to the role I cannot find the role.

Comment: The reason I initially asked this question is because I am constantly installing new db's on my system from my clients and I use one general connection string with the same username and password as default only on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

While the best solution to this specific question of granting execute to all procedures is [the one provided by marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7329579/1901857), the actual question was is there a way to create a single stored procedure and make it available to all databases.

The way to do this is documented at https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sql-making-a-stored-procedure-available-to-all-databases/:

1. Create the stored procedure in the `master` database.
2. It must be named to start with `sp_`, e.g. `sp_MyCustomProcedure`
3. Execute `sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject` passing the name of the procedure, e.g. `EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_MyCustomProcedure`

Here is a simple example which just selects the name of the current database:

```
use master
go

create procedure dbo.sp_SelectCurrentDatabaseName as begin
    select db_name()
end
go

execute sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_SelectCurrentDatabaseName
go
```

Calling `exec dbo.sp_SelectCurrentDatabaseName` on any database will then work.

To mark the procedure as not a system object, there a some nasty hacks suggested at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/793d0add-6fd9-43ea-88aa-c0b3b89b8d70/how-do-i-undo-spmsmarksystemobject?forum=sqltools but it is safest and easiest to just drop and re-create the procedure.

**Caveat**

Of course creating system procedures like this is breaking the common rule of not naming your own procedures as `sp_xxx`, due to the possibility of them conflicting with built-in procedures in future versions of SQL Server. Therefore this should be done with care and not just create a load of randomly named procedures which you find useful.

A common simple way to avoid this is to add your own company/personal prefix to the procedure which Microsoft is unlikely to use, e.g. `sp_MyCompany_MyCustomProcedure`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a 3 or 4 part name?

InstanceName.DatabaseName.dbo.usp_Name

That procedure could in turn reference objects in other databases using the same conventions.  So you could parameterize the name of the database to be operated on and use dynamic SQL to generate 4 part names to reference objects such as system tables.